# I can't retrieve data from the related table(model) in Laravel6

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I can't retrieve data from the related table.

There are 3 models(tables).

- User
- Chirp (has 'user_id' as foreign key)
- Click (has 'chirp_id' as foreign key)

then I want to retrieve User & Click's data from Chirp model.
So I wrote:

Chirp.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Chirp extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function clicks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Click');
    }
}
```

HomeController.php

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $chirps = Chirp::with(['user','clicks'])
        ->orderBy('posted_at', 'desc')
        ->get();

        return view('home', ['chirps' => $chirps]);
    }
}
```

home.blade.php

```
@foreach($chirps as $chirp)
<div>
    <div>by
    <b>{{ $chirp->user->name }}</b>
        on
        <small>{{ $chirp->posted_at }}</small>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>{{ $chirp->text }}</p>
        <p>{{ $chirp->click->ip_address }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

at home.blade.php, `{{ $chirp->click->ip_address }}` can't be retrieved and get error "Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Trying to get property 'ip_address' of non-object"

However, if I delete it, I can retrieve `{{ $chirp->user->name }}` properly.

Why can't I retrieve Click model from Chirp model, While I can retrieve User model from Chirp model?

Thank you.

Comment: There can be multiple clicks..so you have to use foreach

Comment: On `hasMany` relationship you will be getting Collection not modal. So you will have to loop through the data. It is well documented on Laravel docs. [HasMany](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over your clicks as well:

```
@foreach($chirps as $chirp)
<div>
    <div>by
    <b>{{ $chirp->user->name }}</b>
        on
        <small>{{ $chirp->posted_at }}</small>
    </div>

    @foreach($chirp->clicks as $click)
        <div>
            <p>{{ $chirp->text }}</p>
            <p>{{ $click->ip_address }}</p>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Chirp has many clicks (not click). You have to foreach `$chirp->clicks` in your blade.

```
@foreach ($chirp->clicks as $click)
    <p>This is click id {{ $click->id }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

You've hasMany relation with `Chirp` and `clicks`

And here you're getting many clicks instead of click

```
@foreach($chirp->clicks as $click)
<p>{{ $click->ip_address }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

To debug this problem you can take the following steps:

1. Check if the chirps variable has any data within the controller.

   dd($chirps);
2. If you know you have the data you can take the steps to make your blade better.
   Becasue its a many to many relation you should loop trough the data.

```
    @foreach($chirps as $chirp)
    @foreach($chirp->clicks as $click)
                <div>
                    <p>{{ $chirp->text }}</p>
                    <p>{{ $click->ip_address }}</p>
                </div>
            @endforeach
    @endforeach
```